# Need help understanding a sentence using "to which" repeatedly

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I encountered this sentence: "The funds shall be used to pay all redemption payments due on such date as between each Class A Preferred Share in proportion to the full amounts to which the holders to which such redemption payments are due would otherwise be respectively entitled thereon."

The sentence structure is complex enough to confuse me. Any help?

Comment: Here's my 2 cents: if it's the "to which" part that you find confusing, consider it this way: *the full amounts to which the holders [to which such redemption payments are due] would otherwise be respectively entitled thereon.* The first to which refers to "amounts"; the second one refers to "holders." Basically, the redemption payments are due to the holders that would be otherwise entitled to some given amounts.

Answer (score 1):

You would likely have been spared your confusion had the writer been troubled to refer to "the holders" as people (to whom) rather than as objects (to which).